# get value of post in controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, post

i want to put two button in my view.and two button send value to one controller.
how to check which button press?!
according this link [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320250/codeigniter-change-form-action-by-clicking-buttons)

but in controller not get value of button.any idea?

Comment: Not an expert but if you want to identify that which button is pressed then you can give that button name and get that name in the input post array.

Answer (score 3):

Use the same approach, however in CodeIgniter your code will look a bit clearer :

```
<form action="TheController/PostHandler" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="button1" id="button1" value="Button 1" />
    <input type="submit" name="button2"  id="button2" value="Button 2" />
</form>
```

Because in CodeIgniter, this is  :

```
$something = $this->input->post('something');
```

equivalent to :

```
$something = isset($_POST['something']) ? $_POST['something'] : NULL;
```

Simply check for null values with a code like this :

```
public function PostHandler(){
    if (!is_null($this->input->post('button1'))){
        // code for button 1
    }

    if (!is_null($this->input->post('button2'))){
        // code for button 2
    }
}
```

Comment: i put only this code "if (!is_null($this->input->post('button1'))){}".
but i press button 2 this works.i really confuse.sorry

Comment: I think form helper better https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#form_open

Comment: yes, I had a type under button 2 name, just fixed it

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->input->post('some_data'); // The function returns FALSE (boolean) if some_data not isset
```

Use

```
if($this->input->post('button1')){
$button1 = $this->input->post('some_data',true) //for xss
} else { $bouton1 = false;}
```